# Android : is ok if i just request an ad on app start then show it on second activity?

Tags: android

as you know that is showing the ad when your app starting is a bad idea

but how about just using

```
 mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

on the first Activity ?

then i show it on my second activity ? or admob will consider this as showing on app start ?

i hope someone here clear this confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ads are actually loading in a separate thread, so you can define a common class as adhelper that extend your application class as follows.

```
public class AdHelper extends Application {

AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate();

adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("*");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAds(adRequest);
}}
```

And you can load Ads in any activity as follows

```
 AdHelper ads = (AdHelper) getApplication();
 ads.loadAds(layAd);
```

Also don't forgot to add the class AdHelper to Manifest.

Comment: should i replace " extends Application " with my super class name ?

Comment: thanks but i still need to understand something , i read the "Disallowed interstitial implementations " and i'm wondering if  JUST loading the ad on app start without showing it .  is allowed ?

Comment: Application class is running in UI thread..its not a background process. Since you are defined your AdHelper class in Manifest (under tag application), it will load automatically when app start. So when you want ad in activity you can simply use that instance to load ad

Comment: very useful info thanks Ebin , just if you could answer this part : is it legal to load an ad on app's first activity without showing the add ?

Comment: According to google support (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en) never display an interstitial ad once it loaded. So its ok to hold the ad until an  appropriate place or scenario came.

Comment: Exactly , so that's mean i'm doing ok , requesting ad is not considered displaying .. thank you so much Ebin Joy! Have a nice day :)